# Pexpect interact() exception in python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pexpect

I am in the process of learning Python so apologize if my question is naive.

I was using the `pexpect` `interact()` in my script and it was working with python2.7. But when I use python3 or python3.5 I get the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ap_access.py", line 73, in <module>
    child.interact()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 745, in interact
    self.__interact_copy(escape_character, input_filter, output_filter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 784, in __interact_copy
    self._log(data, 'read')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 121, in _log
    self.logfile.write(s)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Googled up regarding this issue but nothing actually related to the interact() but did not get much information.

```
# Script to log into the device and execute the required shell commands.
log_file = open('logfile.txt', 'w')
for ip in list_of_IP_addresses:
        ip1=str(ip)
        child = pexpect.spawnu('ssh '+username+'@'+ip1, log_file)
        code = child.expect(['Are you sure you want to continue connecting   (yes/no)?', 'Please login: ', 'password :', 'No route to host', pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT])

    if code==0:
            child.sendline('yes')
            code = child.expect(['Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?', 'Please login: ', 'password :', 'No route to host',  pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT])
    if code==1:
            print("Entering the Username")
            child.sendline(username)
            code = child.expect(['Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?', 'Please login: ', 'password :', 'No route to host', pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT])
    if code==2:
            print("Entering the credentials")
            child.sendline(password)
    if code==3:
            print ("Please check for reachability for ip", ip1)
            sys.exit()
    if code==4:
            print ("Looks like there is an error")
            sys.exit(0)
    if code==5:
            print ("Timeout in accessing or logging into ", ip1)
            sys.exit(0)
    child.interact()
```

I will be obliged if could get help on how to get the pexpect interact() to work with python3.x

Thank you.

UPDATE

The new issue that i am facing is that output of commands such a ps, cat of files with larger output cannot be seen in the log file where i am capturing the output. I tried setting the winsize using the "setwinsize", the maxreadsize to larger value but nothing changed.

```
def log_separation():
    sep_file = 'Device_LOG_{}.log'.format(date.today())
    child.logfile = open(sep_file, "a")
    with open(sep_file, 'a+') as log_sep:
        log_sep.write('\n'+'\n')

def mem_cpu():
    mem_file = 'Device_LOG_{}.log'.format(date.today())
    with open(mem_file, 'a+') as cpu:
        cpu.write(str(datetime.datetime.now())+'\n')                                                cpu.write('########################################################'+'\n')
child.sendline('top -n 1')
child.expect('#')
log_separation()
child.sendline('cat /proc/meminfo')
log_separation()
child.expect('#')
child.sendline('cat /proc/slabinfo')
log_separation()
child.expect('#')
child.sendline('cat /proc/tasklets')
log_separation
child.expect('#')
child.sendline('free')
log_separation()
child.expect('#')
child.sendline('ps axww')
log_separation()
child.expect('#')
child.sendline('exit')

# Gets the set of all IP addresses in the given range
list_of_IP_addresses = get_IP_address(ip_addr_lower, ip_addr_upper)

#Opening a file to write the error logs to
log_file = open('logfile.txt', 'w')
with open('Device_Access_log.log', 'w+') as f:
# Script to log into the devices and excute the required shell commands.
    for ip in list_of_IP_addresses:
        ip1=str(ip)
        child = pexpect.spawn('ssh '+username+'@'+ip1, logfile=log_file)
        child.logfile_read = sys.stdout
        code = child.expect(['Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?', 'Please login: ', 'password :', 'No route to host', pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT])
        if code==0:
            child.sendline('yes')
            code = child.expect(['Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?', 'Please login: ', 'password :', 'No route to host',  pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT])
        if code==1:
            print('Entering the Username')
            child.sendline(username)
            code = child.expect(['Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?', 'Please login: ', 'password :', 'No route to host', pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT]) 
        if code==2:
        print('Entering the credentials')
        child.sendline(password)
        mem_cpu()
    stats_file = 'Device_LOG_{}.log'.format(date.today())
    with open(stats_file, 'a+') as eol:
        eol.write('############################### End of log for Device '+ip1+' ###############################################'+'\n')
        eol.write('########################################################################################################'+'\n')
    if code==3:
        print ('Ip address error', ip1)
        f.write('No route to host '+ip1+'\n')
    if code==4:
                print ('Error connecting to ', ip1)
        f.write('Error connecting to '+ip1+'\n')
    if code==5:
                print ('Timeout in accessing or logging into ', ip1)
        f.write('Timeout in accessing or logging into '+ip1+'\n')
```

I can see the output till "free", the output of the ps command is not seen in the log files.

Comment: Could you please give some minimal code example, where you use said function, so that we can try to reproduce your error message?

Comment: Dear Thomas,  I have added the code. I am trying to get a range of ip addresses to login into one at a time and execute a few commands and then exit.

Comment: The poster appears to be asking two questions in one. The first one, the issue with `interact` appears to be an open bug. See https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues/506. It does not look like Pexpect is a very active project, so it's unclear when this will be fixed. The issue itself is from 2018.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to your problem [here](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues/159): If you change the beginning of your code to this:

```
for ip in list_of_IP_addresses:
    ip1=str(ip)
    child = pexpect.spawnu('ssh '+username+'@'+ip1, logfile=sys.stdout.buffer) # <-- add the logfile keyword here and use sys.stdout.buffer (byte mode) instead of sys.stdout
    ##child.logfile = sys.stdout #<-- comment out this line
```

It should work. Note: I couldn't test your code in its entirety. The `if` cases didn't work for me, as I use ssh keys. Also, for me the keyboard echoing repeated each letter three times. Anyway, I hope this helps you a bit.

**EDIT**:

I did not find anything about the triple echoing of the typed input, but it has something to do with the fact that you set `stdout` as logfile. If instead you create a logfile, the problem goes away:

```
mylogfile = open('logfile.txt', 'wb')
for ip in list_of_IP_addresses:
    ip1=str(ip)
    child = pexpect.spawnu('ssh '+username+'@'+ip1, logfile=mylogfile)
    child.interact()
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas. Actually the three letter echoing is what i saw with python2.7. I thought python3 would help. On googling it was said an upgrade helped solve the problem. But mine was already on the latest with i checked with "pip install --upgrade pexpect" and "python3 pip install --upgrade pexpect".

Comment: Just tested it out and found the echoing is not seen anymore. Since before this update the issue was persisting i moved to using python2.7 and i seem to have new problem relating to getting the output of sendline commands to a file.

Comment: Well, if you have a new, unrelated, problem, it would be best if you would write a new question.

Comment: Unfortunately i need to wait for 1 day to post a new question. I have updated the question with a working part of my code and where i am facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am facing the same issue, but in a different way.  I want the logfile to go to a file. Depending on how I open it, I get a different error.  Behold:

```
with open("ssh_run.log", "ab") as logfile:
            print( f"Connecting to {self.pxe_user}@{self.pxe_server_ipv4}\n{cmd_2_ssh}" )
            y5: Tuple = pexpect.run( cmd_2_ssh, \
                # (?i) turns on case-insensitive mode
                    events={"(?i)password: ": self.pxe_passwd + "\n"}, \
                    withexitstatus = True, logfile=logfile,
                    timeout = 20 )
```

I opened the log file in mode "ab".  The error message I get is:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

But if I change the mode to "a" or "at" instead of "ab", I get:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

I also tried the encoding parameter with the `open` function call, but that did not solve the problem.

I am running python 3.6.9 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: In fact, it was *exactly* the same problem and it had *exactly* the same solution: change the argument to the `logfile` to be `logfile.buffer`.